# Creating a Library without using github repository

Tags: android, android-library

i have a project to create android library for my client, i searched and look several tutorial, but they recommend me for using github and publish it using jitpack. 
My questions is

**is there any other way to create library without using github repository?**

you see, i want to create library without making it public, only me and my client know the resource code, i know there is private hosting in github but it must paid for use that.
is there any option for archive this? thanks

Comment: why you try to upload? share just your private aar manually.

Comment: Most companies typically already have a private code repository themselves... You can self-host a Git server

Comment: @AbhayKoradiya can you tell me how to done that you know this is first time i create a library

Comment: @cricket_007 it is? well i will ask my client company about that, thanks for sharing

Comment: Every company I've been to has had either Nexus/Sonatype or Artifactory for hosting artifacts (jars/aars) and also an internal SVN or Git server, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use the GitHub public repository,  there's another alternative you can use [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/product/pricing), it's more like GitHub and the best part is, it offers free private repository.  And for library publishing you can use jCenter,  maven,  bintray and more,  there are so much options available there.

Comment: GitLab is another option

Comment: @MSaifulhakim But, when you publish to jcenter or maven, it become public.

Comment: @AbhayKoradiya no I don't think so,  as it is clearly mentioned in the official Android Guide that we can publish both public and private type library to jCenter and maven.  Link here   https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Building-your-own-Android-library#publishing